# Setting Context Path in nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, docker

I am trying to serve my webpack bundled app and files from a context path. Nginx Config file is as below:

**nginx.conf**

```
server {

  listen 80;
  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index  index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /mfeexample/index.html;
  }

  location /mfeexample/ {   
    try_files $uri $uri/ /mfeexample/index.html;
  }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# Build Environment
FROM node:14.2.0-alpine as build

# Working Directory
WORKDIR /app

#Copying node package files to working directory
COPY package.* .

#Installing app dependency
RUN npm install --silent

#Copy all the code
COPY . .

#RUN Production build
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:stable-alpine

# Deploy the built application to Nginx server
# /usr/share/nginx/html is the Nginx static directory used to serve the appliation
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html/mfeexample

# Remove the default Nginx configuration in Nginx Container
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Apply the new configuration file
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Expose the Application on PORT 80
EXPOSE 80

# Start Nginx server
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Now looking at the network tab in browser, I found all the files are being served at http://localhost:3000/mfeexample/, that is exactly what I wanted. However, when I try nested route it breaks, nested route I mean http://localhost:3000/mfeexample/customer/, looking at the network tab again, nginx is looking for files under http://localhost:3000/mfeexample/customer/index.html, but I want nginx to always find the files from http://localhost:3000/mfeexample.

PS: Please keep in mind I am new to nginx and I have been doing trial and error method to  get upto this point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you try to clarify your question with clear examples: "When I request URL A, I want to get file B from filesystem". "When I request URL C, I want to get file D from filesystem". It is a bit difficult to see what you need from your question. Please also clarify what you mean by context path.

Comment: Context path I mean the URL path at which the application needs to be served. In my case, I want the application to be served at /mfeexample and not at the root level. All the files should also be served from /mfeexample.

Comment: Please add exact examples like I requested above. Without clear examples this question cannot be answered.

Comment: To give an example, when I hit the URL http://localhost:3000/ react application should not be rendered but when I hit the URL http://localhost:3000/mfeexample/ the application should render it's content and also serve all the static files from http://localhost/mfeexample. 
Now if I try nested route i.e http://localhost:3000/mfeexample/customer/ the same react application should serve all the static files from http://localhost:3000/mfeexample/ but should render the content in http://localhost:3000/mfeexample/customer/
I hope this helps.

Comment: The application should return main.js from the React application which should live at http://localhost:3000/mfeexample. The user should be able to visit either http://localhost:3000/mfeexample or http://localhost:3000/mfeexample/customer, however the current issue is that when going to http://localhost:3000/mfeexample/customer the server attempts to serve main.js from http://localhost:3000/mfeexample/customer instead of the base path at http://localhost:3000/mfeexample

Comment: Sorry, but your example still does not show what filesystem path should each URL serve. Please edit the question and add the URL - path mappings there.